# About says version 2.46 when I install version 2.79

Tags: installation

I have no clue why when I hit the about button, it tells me that it's version 2.46 when I installed version 2.79 using the blender-2.79.windows64.msi! just curious as to why it tells me I have version 2.46 after I install version 2.79???

Comment: Where did you get blender? Can you show an image?

Answer (score 1):

Guess I had version 2.46 installed and did NOT realize it. So when I installed 2.79, it installed to a different folder (Blender instead of Blender Foundation which is what 2.46 installed to). I was opening the wrong version and didnt realize I was doing so.